# Cordova plugin not able to call native ios method from javascript interface

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, apache-cordova

Cordova plugin not able to call native ios method from javascript interface .

I have created a simple cordova plugin for iOS platform and added it into a cordova project. But somehow I am not able to call native code from JS layer of plugin. I have tried all possible solution given in the stackoverflow and cordova.apache.org site.

below is my code please check it and let me know if I am missing any step -

index.html

```
<body>
<div class="app">
<h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
<div id="deviceready" class="Merchant">
    <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
    <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p> <br>
    <button onclick="testInit()">Click</button>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/testXyz.js"></script>
</body>
```

index.js

```
var app = {
initialize: function() {
 document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
},

 onDeviceReady: function() {
    this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},

// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
   }
 };

 app.initialize();
```

testXyz.js

```
function testInit() {
  "use strict";
  var sign = "xyz";
  var environ = "S1";
  var mp = cordova.require("cordova_Plugin_xyzPlugin.xyzPlugin");
  var success  = function() { alert('win!');  }
  var fail = function() { alert('fail!'); }
  mp.coolMethod(sign, environ, true, true, success, fail);
}
```

plugin.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<plugin id="cordova_Plugin_xyzPlugin" version="0.0.1" 
xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<name>xyzPlugin</name>
<js-module name="xyzPlugin" src="www/xyzPlugin.js">
    <clobbers target="cordova.plugins.xyzPlugin" />
</js-module><platform name="ios">
    <config-file parent="/*" target="config.xml">
        <feature name="xyzPlugin">
            <param name="ios-package" value="xyzPlugin" />
        </feature>
    </config-file>
    <source-file src="src/ios/xyzPlugin.h" />
    <source-file src="src/ios/xyzPlugin.m" />
 </platform>
</plugin>
```

xyzPlugin.js

```
cordova.define("cordova_Plugin_xyzPlugin.xyzPlugin", function(require, exports, module) {

var exec = require('cordova/exec');
var xyzPlugin = {};

xyzPlugin.coolMethod = function(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, success, error)
 {
   alert(JSON.stringify(cordova)); 
  //Here I am getting Alert.

   cordova.exec(success, error, "xyzPlugin", "coolMethod", [arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3]); 

  // This is not working, from here I am not able to call native method.

 };
  module.exports = xyzPlugin;

});
```

Native ios plugin -

xyzPlugin.h

```
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>

@interface xyzPlugin : CDVPlugin
- (void)coolMethod:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
@end
```

xyxPlugin.m

```
#import "xyxPlugin.h"

@implementation xyxPlugin

-(void)coolMethod:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
 {
   CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;
   NSString* echo = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

   if (echo != nil && [echo length] > 0) {
    pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:echo];
  } else {
    pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR];
 }

  [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
 }
@end
```

Please help to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: One file you didn't show is plugin.xml and how you define the js-module in it.

Comment: Added plugin.xml file

Comment: maybe try `<clobbers target="xyzPlugin" />` instead?

Comment: did this resolve your issue? @PremaJanoti

Comment: Yes, it got resolved.